# everytime i try to navigate, i navigete to the same activity

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

can someone please help me? i'm very noob and i'm desperate, i'm trying to do a navigation between 2 activities, i make Intents and startActivity but everytime i press the button it navigates to the initial activity, over and over again.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.txtCadastrar.setOnClickListener() {
            telaCadastro()
        }

        binding.buttonEntrar.setOnClickListener() {
            val nome = binding.textoNome.text.toString()
            val email = binding.textoEmail.text.toString()
            val senha = binding.textoSenha.text.toString()

            if(nome.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || senha.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Preencha os campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                entrar()
            }
        }

    }
    fun telaCadastro(){
        val cadastroTela = Intent(this@MainActivity,CadastroActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(cadastroTela)
    }

    fun entrar(){
        val calendarioTela = Intent(this@MainActivity,MainActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(calendarioTela)
    }
}
```

please help me i'm going insane